# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray) error

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I try to train a tensorflow model. But I got error.

`Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).`

Here my fit codes:

`model.fit(self.datas.trainImages, self.datas.trainLabels,self.datas.batch_size, epochs =self.datas.epochs)`

My self.datas.trainImages is numpy.array() its shape is (16,) it has 16 sample and their sizes is 28x28, it is mnist dataset.

```
self.train_dataset = [[cv2.imread(image0),0],[cv2.imread(image1),1],[cv2.imread(image2),2],[...],[...]]
self.trainDataset = numpy.array(self.train_dataset)
        
self.trainImages, self.trainLabels = numpy.asarray(self.trainDataset[:,0])/255,self.trainDataset[:,1] #.astype(numpy.float32)/



self.val_dataset = [[cv2.imread(image0),0],[cv2.imread(image1),1],[cv2.imread(image2),2],[...],[...]]

self.valDataset = numpy.array(self.val_dataset)#.astype(numpy.float32)
self.valImages, self.valLabels = numpy.asarray(self.valDataset[:,0])/255,self.valDataset[:,1] #.astype(numpy.float32)/255
```

I tried to use astype or numpy.ndarray but I got another errors. I am sure of that all datas in the self.datas.trainImages is float numbers and has same shape.

Comment: What were the "another errors".  What's the `trainImages.dtype`?

Comment: @hpaulj I checked it is object, but its values is number.

Comment: @hpaulj if I convert dtype into numpy.float 32, I get this error : `setting an array element with a sequence.
`

Comment: That tells me that the array is `object` dtype, with elements that vary in shape.  It can't be converted to a multidimensional numeric dtype array.  Which is the root of the tensor conversion error.

Comment: @hpaulj I checked the element shapes in the self.trainImages, and all of them have same size (28,28)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it be possible to print out some type of error output?

Personally, I was having a similar issue and by coating my input with "np.stack()" it added an extra dimension, changed the shape of the array and allowed it to work.

i.e.

```
images = np.stack(self.data.trainImages)
```

EDIT: Removed irrelevant information

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your first answer is solved my problem. But it is weird because I used my same  method before maybe 4-6 months and it was worked and I have not updated my tensorflow version. I got another error, I will open new post for new error.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read the fit() call you did, the second part of my answer was for 2 inputs 1 output.

Comment: Not problem, I got what you mean, thanks again everything.